# Correct way of writing xsl:value-of in XSLT

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, xslt, xpath

I am trying to write XSLT to transform my XML from one format to another. When I apply my `.xslt` file to the XML file in VS 2010, **the output XML structure is created without any problem. But it does not fill in data expected by processing `xsl:value-of`.**

When I use `XMLSpy` and evaluate the `XPath` expression, it says `no result` for the expressions in following XSLT. But when I use `node()` function at the end of the XPath expression, it shows the value!

1. What is the correct way of writing XPath?
2. Does `node()` and `text()` kind of functions really necessary everytime to read the element content (when it has no child elements) ? If no, why XmlSpy too does not give result without those functions?
3. Sometimes (when i change the template match value from "/" to the "ServiceMessage" ) while debugging XSLT, VS 2010 steps into built in template rules. Why is it so? How can I get rid of built in templates in VS 2010?

I have followed [w3school tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_value_of.asp) to begin with. I am new to XSLT.

Here is my XML which I want to transform to some other XML format.

```
<ServiceMessage xmlns="http://requestservice/requests" xmlns:req="http://requestservice/requests/xmlstds">

<TypeOfReq> General </TypeOfReq>
<Details>
   <Id> 123456789 </Id>
   <SenderDetails>
        <Sender id="345"></Sender>
   </SenderDetails>
</Details>

</ServiceMessage>
```

**This is my XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <request>
      <requestType>
        <xsl:value-of select="ServiceMessage/TypeOfReq" />
      </requestType>
      <Id>
        <xsl:value-of select="ServiceMessage/Details/Id"/>
      </Id>
      <senderId>
        <xsl:value-of select="ServiceMessage/Details/SenderDetails/Sender/@id"/>
      </senderId>
    </request>

  </xsl:template>



</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have written the xpath correctly from a syntatic point of view. The problem you are actually having is actually to do with namespaces. In your XML you have specified a default namespace

```
<ServiceMessage xmlns="http://requestservice/requests">
```

This means all the child elements, unless otherwise specified, with belong to that namespace. However, in your XSLT, there is no reference to this namepsace at all, and so the XSLT is looking for elements which do not have a namespace specified. This is not the case for your XML.

For XSLT 1.0, you will need to declare the namespace, like so:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:s="http://requestservice/requests">
```

You would then explicitly state where it is used for matching the elements

```
<xsl:value-of select="s:ServiceMessage/s:TypeOfReq" />
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:s="http://requestservice/requests">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <request>
         <requestType>
            <xsl:value-of select="s:ServiceMessage/s:TypeOfReq"/>
         </requestType>
         <Id>
            <xsl:value-of select="s:ServiceMessage/s:Details/s:Id"/>
         </Id>
         <senderId>
            <xsl:value-of select="s:ServiceMessage/s:Details/s:SenderDetails/s:Sender/@id"/>
         </senderId>
      </request>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML, the following is output

```
<request xmlns:s="http://requestservice/requests">
   <requestType> General </requestType>
   <Id> 123456789 </Id>
   <senderId>345</senderId>
</request>
```

Do note the choice of the letter 's' here is purely arbitrary, it could be anything really.

Comment: Awesome! It worked. I'll accept it as an answer. But do you have any idea, why XmlSpy does not provide result without `node()` or `text()` functions? And why does it evaluate the Xpath expression correctly (i use node() in this case)  without the namespace specified in the expression?

Comment: node() will match elements, text, comments and processing instructions, whereas text() will only match text(). You normally would not use text() with xsl:value-of because this function will return the text of a node anyway. Do note (in XSLT1.0) if you do xsl:value-of and your xpath expression matches multiple nodes, it will only return the text of the first node it matches.

Comment: Accepting this as an answer since it has identified problem exactly and provided the solution as well. Other question about the VS built in template is answered by @Filburt.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your 3rd question "How can I get rid of built in templates?"

If you don't specify a template for an element occurring in your xml, in your case VS will apply the **identity template** which will simply copy the source element to your output.

```
<xsl:template match="/ | @* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

See [Microsoft's explanation on built in templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552390.aspx) for details.

*(atm I can't tell if it's possible to turn this off since I only have VS Express here which doesn't offer Xslt debugging)*

As a general rule you should always specify templates for all elements you want to process, so your basic xslt will always start with

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:s="http://requestservice/requests">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

next, in your case, add a template for the root element *ServiceMessage*

```
<xsl:template match="s:ServiceMessage">
    <!-- usually apply-templates, in your case create new output element(s) -->
<xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks @Filburt. It helped me to understand the problem I faced during debugging in VS 2010.

Comment: >> If you don't specify a template for an element occurring in your xml, VS will apply the identity template which will simply copy the source element to your output.<< This is not correct.

Comment: @torazaburo If you know better then please let us know - otherwise my answer contains a (shortened and simplified) version of [Microsofts own definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552390.aspx)

Comment: The default rule does NOT copy the source element. It merely executes `<xsl:apply-templates>` on its children. Were this not the case, there would be no reason for the copying boilerplate we see so often in solutions to problems such as this one ("copy the XML but do this little transformation on the way..."). The only thing that is copied to output by the default rules is text nodes. The MS page you refer to does NOT say that the default rules COPY the nodes, it says that it PROCESSES them.